# Recargar SPAN sin perder estilos

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

Buen día

Estoy usando ajax para recargar un span y todo funciona bien con `$("#currentCart").load(" #currentCart");` pero el problema es que al recargar pierde el formato ya que el span esta posicionado como absoluto dentro de un Div padre que tiene una imagen.

¿Como puedo hacer para que siga respetando el CSS cuando recargue con ajax?

Nota. Si recargo la pagina completamente digamos con location.reload(), se vuelve a mostrar todo en su lugar.

EL codigo HTML es:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 cartPadre" id="currentCart">
    <a href="#" title="Carrito">
        <img src="../../assets/icons/carrito-01.svg" alt="" width="55">
            <span class="cartItem text-info">
                <=$cart->countItem();?>
            </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: En ese código no existe el contenedor con `id="currentCart"`, no hay forma de saber lo que estás haciendo. Edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo del HTML ya cargado y cómo realizas la actualización por AJAX.

Comment: Error mio, copie la versión anterior.

Comment: Te falta la parte donde realizas la actualización por AJAX, tanto en Javascript como en PHP. Por favor proporciona toda la información necesaria para tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery es obsoleto e ineficiente en muchas cosas, no digo que todo, a tal grado de complicar mas las cosas como te ha pasado.

Mi recomendación es utilizar las funciones `$.get` o `$.post` para hacer una llamada Ajax y la respuesta agrégala con `$(elemento).append(data)` o con `$(elemento).html(data)`

Quedaría algo mas o menos así

```
$.get(url, function(response){
  $(elemento).append(resposne);
  $(elemento).html(resposne);
});

$.get(url, {...variables}, function(response){
  $(elemento).append(resposne);
  $(elemento).html(resposne);
});
```

Si usas `$.post` es exactamente igual

Comment: Trate con esta solución, pero no me esta agregando el dato del ajax al DOM

Comment: Como ya se te ha solicitado antes publica todo el código involucrado tanto HTML como Javascript para poder determinar que estas haciendo y donde puede estar fallando.